# Check if artifact or dependency exist in a private repository

Tags: maven, repository, pom.xml, nexus, artifact

This is my POM file that generate a **JAR artifact** and it is **stored in a private repository** with **Nexus Repository**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.home.mac</groupId>
  <artifactId>hyper-dev</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>  
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.home.mac</groupId>
        <artifactId>hyper-test-linux</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I want to check two things:

- If the **artifact** that I am going to install **hyper-dev-0.0.1** exists in my private maven repository.
- If the dependency with **artifactID: hyper-test-linux-0.3.5** exists in my private maven repository.

Is it possible?

Comment: What kind of problem are you trying to solve? Why do you need to do that?

Comment: @khmarbaise Check if exists. If  exists not generate again, and if exists generate and upload it.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your answer?

Comment: @khmarbaise Check before generating the artifact, if it is stored in my private Nexus repository. If that version is not stored, generate it using mvn clean install.

Comment: You express the same in different flavours but unfortunately I don't understand what your real problem is? If you have already a release you will fail cause Nexus will not allow to redeploy the same version again which shows you have a flaw in your CI process which should automatically increment the version etc. ? Furthermore I would recommend not to change the conventions in Maven means `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>`....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Nexus' Rest Api](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/search-api) to check if an artifact exists.

For example, the url

```
http://<your private nexus server>:8081/service/rest/beta/search/assets?group=org.home.mac&name=hyper-dev&version=0.0.1&maven.extension=jar&maven.classifier
```

will show you if the artifact `hyper-dev` in the version `0.0.1` is available in your private Nexus.

If you want to automate the process, you can use a command line tool like `wget` or `curl` to access the Rest Api, as shown in the document linked above.

*Remark*: I would like to repeat the comment of [khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise) that is usually not possible to upload a *released* artifact to Nexus if it already exists in the repository. If you want to upload it again, you have to increase the version and by doing so, create a new artifact. It would be an unwanted feature to update existing artifacts, as Maven assumes that a downloaded artifact will never change and caches them locally on every machine.

*Snapshot* artifacts can actually be updated, but you have asked about released artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

For Nexus2 (using as example org.jboss.security:jboss-negotiation-toolkit:3.0.2.Final)

curl -I -s -u admin:admin123 http://mynexusserver/service/local/repositories/mymavenrepo/content/org/jboss/security/jboss-negotiation-toolkit/3.0.2.Final/jboss-negotiation-toolkit-3.0.2.Final.war | grep HTTP

This will print "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" if found, "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found" if not found

Comment: Thanks, i use nexus3, so my curl is a bit different `curl -I -s -u ${NEXUS_USER}:${NEXUS_PWD} https://${NEXUS_SERVER}/repository/${REPO}/${GROUP_ID}/${POM_ARTIFACT}/${VERSION}/${POM_ARTIFACT}-${VERSION}.${PACKAGING} | grep HTTP)`